# Can someone help me resolve this Driver Error in Geopandas?

Tags: python, geopandas

Can someone help me resolve the driver error below? I've tried every resource I could find but nothing works. Thanks in advance.

pip install fiona geopandas pyproj

import geopandas as gpd

## Read the KML file into a GeoDataFrame

kml_file = r"C:\Users\1282345\Desktop\KML to Shapefile\Eval Traffic Counter Locations.kmz"
gdf = gpd.read_file(kml_file, driver='KML')

## Write the GeoDataFrame to a shapefile

shp_file = r"C:\Users\1282345\Desktop\KML to Shapefile\Eval Traffic Counter Locations.shp"
gdf.to_file(shp_file, driver='ESRI Shapefile')
`

```
CPLE_OpenFailedError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
File fiona\ogrext.pyx:136, in fiona.ogrext.gdal_open_vector()

File fiona\_err.pyx:291, in fiona._err.exc_wrap_pointer()

CPLE_OpenFailedError: 'C:\\Users\\1282345\\Desktop\\KML to Shapefile\\Eval Traffic Counter Locations.kmz' not recognized as a supported file format.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

DriverError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[2], line 5
      3 # Read the KML file into a GeoDataFrame
      4 kml_file = r"C:\\Users\\1282345\\Desktop\\KML to Shapefile\\Eval Traffic Counter Locations.kmz"
----> 5 gdf = gpd.read_file(kml_file, driver='KML')
      7 # Write the GeoDataFrame to a shapefile
      8 shp_file = r"C:\\Users\\1282345\\Desktop\\KML to Shapefile\\Eval Traffic Counter Locations.shp"

File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\geopandas\io\file.py:248, in _read_file(filename, bbox, mask, rows, engine, **kwargs)
    245     else:
    246         path_or_bytes = filename
--> 248     return _read_file_fiona(
    249         path_or_bytes, from_bytes, bbox=bbox, mask=mask, rows=rows, **kwargs
    250     )
    252 else:
    253     raise ValueError(f"unknown engine '{engine}'")

File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\geopandas\io\file.py:289, in _read_file_fiona(path_or_bytes, from_bytes, bbox, mask, rows, where, **kwargs)
    286     reader = fiona.open
    288 with fiona_env():
--> 289     with reader(path_or_bytes, **kwargs) as features:
    290         crs = features.crs_wkt
    291         # attempt to get EPSG code

File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\fiona\env.py:457, in ensure_env_with_credentials.<locals>.wrapper(*args, **kwds)
    454     session = DummySession()
    456 with env_ctor(session=session):
--> 457     return f(*args, **kwds)

File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\fiona\__init__.py:308, in open(fp, mode, driver, schema, crs, encoding, layer, vfs, enabled_drivers, crs_wkt, allow_unsupported_drivers, **kwargs)
    305     path = parse_path(fp)
    307 if mode in ("a", "r"):
--> 308     colxn = Collection(
    309         path,
    310         mode,
    311         driver=driver,
    312         encoding=encoding,
    313         layer=layer,
    314         enabled_drivers=enabled_drivers,
    315         allow_unsupported_drivers=allow_unsupported_drivers,
    316         **kwargs
    317     )
    318 elif mode == "w":
    319     colxn = Collection(
    320         path,
    321         mode,
   (...)
    330         **kwargs
    331     )

File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\fiona\collection.py:243, in Collection.__init__(self, path, mode, driver, schema, crs, encoding, layer, vsi, archive, enabled_drivers, crs_wkt, ignore_fields, ignore_geometry, include_fields, wkt_version, allow_unsupported_drivers, **kwargs)
    241 if self.mode == "r":
    242     self.session = Session()
--> 243     self.session.start(self, **kwargs)
    244 elif self.mode in ("a", "w"):
    245     self.session = WritingSession()

File fiona\ogrext.pyx:588, in fiona.ogrext.Session.start()

File fiona\ogrext.pyx:143, in fiona.ogrext.gdal_open_vector()
```

DriverError: 'C:\Users\1282345\Desktop\KML to Shapefile\Eval Traffic Counter Locations.kmz' not recognized as a supported file format.

Can someone help me resolve the driver error below? I've tried every resource I could find but nothing works. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. This is not a code-writing or tutoring service. It is not possible to provide a specific answer without you providing sufficient information to understand your problem. Please see: [Why is Can someone help me? not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)  for more details.